# Ubuntu Boot From Flash Drive Out of Range

Tags: boot, usb, monitor

Seems to be booting from the flash drive and screen turns black and a small box appears with "Out Of Range" appears. I have been able to get to the grub menu and boot without graphics. I tried to change the display resolution, but the only 2 options were 800 x 600 and 1280 x 768. How do I get other resolutions and graphics?
I also tried to change to the native resolution (1920 x 1080) before attempting to boot and got the same out of range box.

Comment: You will have higher chances to receive an answer if you will provide more details such us: version of Ubuntu, model of the computer, more detailed steps you have taken and how did you create the bootable USB. Edit your Question with these informations.

Comment: I've had this occur because of faulty ISO and/or bad write to the usb-media, ie. did you verify your ISO & write to media?  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck  (the second one varies on release; which you didn't provide)